# telegram bot manual location from the user

Tags: geolocation, telegram-bot, custom-keyboard

I am using a telegram bot to detect if an user is on a specific place. Unlikely when I send a custom keyboard with "request_location=true" the user has the ability to set the location manually if it cannot be detected from the phone. I don't want this to happen or at least be advised in the message received from the webhook that the location has not been automatically detected. Is there any known way to accomplish this ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to find out whether it's user's current location or a chosen spot on map](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43716042/how-to-find-out-whether-its-users-current-location-or-a-chosen-spot-on-map)

Comment: I just noticed that this question was asked before the one I mentioned so the duplication would be the other way around. But as long as the other one received an answer, it's still worth mentioning.