# How to find out whether it's user's current location or a chosen spot on map

Tags: telegram, telegram-bot

I need to get user's current location.

I can ask for location by location keyboard and user will send his current location clicking on it. But he can also reply to message, choose any location on map and share it.

Either way, the returned results to my Bot are identical.(At least as I see.)

Is there a way or a trick to make sure that the shared location is also his current?

FYI - I'm using [TeleBot](https://github.com/mullwar/telebot) library written in [Node.js](https://nodejs.org).(Even though I don't think it will affect the answer.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My workaround is I ask user send the location twice.

If two location are different. I will keep ask them to send new location.

Another solution is I create another inline bot which will create an Venue result which includes security check. The Venue is generate by the inline bot using current user location.

Anyway, I would like to use native telegram bot api to do that. Wish Telegram team add this feature in future.

Updates: Telegram 4.4 released a new feature - live location which is very difficult to cheat https://telegram.org/blog/live-locations

Comment: I think "two locations" might be a little annoying sometimes because GPS is not that accurate but hey it's an interesting idea.

Comment: Now this live location is what I was looking for. Although it can still be hacked by fake GPS apps (well what can't be hacked nowadays...!), we can count on this one.

Comment: But how do you check is it live location or not? Telegram don't have any unique message type for live location messages, it looks exactly like simple location message with longitude and latitude…

Comment: If live location, the interval between two locations message updates is same.

Comment: @IliaSachev after getting message with location you start to wait edit of THIS message and actually save the edited location that you will receive. Editing will mean, that's it's "live location", and I recommend to save this second coordinates because first one for some device problems might be from previous location (Which user sent before), so they might be quite different.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to do that :(

I also have the same problem.

Comment: I contacted Telegram Bot Support and they also said this is impossible and they "almost certainly" won't add it in the future either.

Comment: @AhmadM didn't they tell you why? Maybe privacy reasons?

Comment: @91DarioDev I didn't ask why but I'm sure it has privacy reasons because Telegram doesn't like "forcing" it's users. Guess we should accept that.